# How to solve this Cubic Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

How to solve the below Cubic Inequality:

$$n^3-36n+64\le0$$

My try below:

$$n(n^2-36)\le-64$$
$$n(n^2-6^2)\le-64$$
$$n(n-6)(n+6)\le-64$$

I'm stuck here. Please help.

The answer is : $n\le4$

Answer (score 1):

It's $$n^3-2n^2+2n^2-4n-32n+64\leq0$$ or
$$(n-2)(n^2+2n-32)\leq0$$ or
$$(n-2)(n+1+\sqrt{33})(n+1-\sqrt{33})\leq0,$$
which gives the answer:
$$(-\infty,-1-\sqrt{33}]\cup[2,-1+\sqrt{33}]$$

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is to set the right hand sids equal to zero, like you started. If you then want to factor the equation, you can use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to look for possible (rational) solutions. Then you would have found that $n=2$ (or $n=6$, or $=-6$) is a solution. From there, you can factor $n-2$ and determine the other factor, which should be $n^2+2n-32$. You can solve that last equation using the abc-formula.

Then you can solve the inequality: the left hand side is smaller than zero if and only if either one or three factors are negative. This gives the solution of the inequality.

Such an approach works best for looking for cubic equations that should be solved manually. When the right hand side is a number unequal to $0$, you will not be able to get any further. Keep this in mind.